# Converting one-dimensional structured array to 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a one-dimensional structured array e.g.([ (1,2), (3,4) ]) and want to convert it to 2D numpy array ([ [1,2], [3,4] ]). Right now I am using list comprehension and then np.asarray()

```
list_of_lists = [list(elem) for elem in array_of_tuples]
array2D = np.asarray(list_of_lists)
```

This doesn't look very efficient - is there a better way? Thanks.

NOTE: the initial version of this question was mentioning "numpy array of tuples" instead of one-dimensional structured array. This might be useful for confused python newbies as me.

Comment: Why not directly use `np.asarray` on `array_of_tuples`, won't that work?

Comment: ... How did you get an array of 2-tuples in the first place? :-)

Comment: Is your "numpy array of tuples" a one-dimensional structured array, or a numpy array with dtype `object`, or something else?

Comment: @Divakar np.asarray gives the same output as input, cause the input is also a numpy array

Comment: I thought the input is an array of tuples!

Comment: @mgilson it is an output of a library function which reads a ply file.

Comment: @Divakar it is numpy array (of tuples)

Comment: I am not sure if I am following, but try `array_of_tuples.astype(float)` or `array_of_tuples.astype(int)`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser it is one-dimensional and has `dtype=[('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4'), ('confidence', '<f4'), ('intensity', '<f4')]`, hope this answers the question

Comment: @Divakar: It is a one-dimensional structured array, so when it is printed, it looks like an array of tuples.  The elements in each "tuple" are the values of the fields in the structure.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Yeah now it makes sense, I was going with the assumption of object dtype. Thanks for clearing up that.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, yup, sorry for initial confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a comment, you stated that the array is one-dimensional, with dtype `[('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4'), ('confidence', '<f4'), ('intensity', '<f4')]`.  All the fields in the structured array are the same type (`'<f4'`), so you can create a 2-d view using the `view` method:

```
In [13]: x
Out[13]: 
array([(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0), (6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0)], 
      dtype=[('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4'), ('confidence', '<f4'), ('intensity', '<f4')])

In [14]: x.view('<f4').reshape(len(x), -1)
Out[14]: 
array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.],
       [  6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.]], dtype=float32)
```

In this case, the `view` method gives a flattened result, so we have to reshape it into a 2-d array using the `reshape` method.

Comment: Thanks this works like a charm. I shall edit my question above to state that it is a structured array.